# Chord of a tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

My question is what is a exact definition of chord in a tree?? like
if we have the following tree:

```
    a
  b   c
d e  f g
```

is a tree then dbacg is a chord as I have come to know..
Can ebacg or ebacf also a chord???

Comment: maybe it's cord? never heard it before, but that at least makes some sense.

Comment: Removed "c" tag since it has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Where did you come across this term used in this context?

Comment: actually there was a question asked to my friend in some test that he had a value and he had to make a c program whether that sum exists in tree as a chord which is like  dbacg or dbe or fcg... the tree which does not have a left or a right child does not have a chord... He asked the teacher the same question and the teacher replied as I hace written in the question.... that raised a doubt in my mind...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is nothing called chord (or cord) in a tree.

There is a definition of “[chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph)” in general graph, but it operates on cycles. And trees never have cycles by definition, so, following this definition, no tree has a chord.

Maybe your teacher uses that name to mean something that is usually called differently? Did he give you a definition?

Comment: thats what I was thinking how a chord can exist in a tree.. but then this question came up with my friend in some exam, puzzled me out... searched on net didnt got anything...no I have no definition thats where the real problem starts if definition is given then the answer to the problem is crystal clear

Answer (score 0):

chord is a term used for spanning trees. A spanning tree of a graph G is a subgraph that is a tree 
and contains all vertices of G with minimum number of edges possible. If T is the set of spanning tree edges, then any graph edge not in T is a chord of the spanning tree.

Also note that a graph can have more than one spanning trees.